# undefined method `twitter_source_twitter_aggregation_methods_path' for #<#<Class:0xb982e10>:0xc104ef4>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, associations, nested-routes

I have 3 nested resources: sources, twitter_source and twitter_aggregation_methods.

The relationship of their respective models is as follows:

**sources.rb**

```
has_many :twitter_sources

has_many :rss_sources
```

**twitter_source.rb**

```
has_many :twitter_aggregation_methods

belongs_to :source
```

**twitter_aggregation_method.rb**

```
belongs_to :twitter_source
```

The **config/routes.rb** is set up as follows:

```
resources :sources do
 resources :rss_sources
   resources :twitter_sources do
     resources :twitter_aggregation_methods
     resources :influencer_trends do
       resources :trends
     end
   end
end
```

When I try to add a new `twitter_aggreggation_method` I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in TwitterAggregationMethods#new

Showing /home/notebook/work/abacus/app/views/twitter_aggregation_methods/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `twitter_source_twitter_aggregation_methods_path' for #<#<Class:0xb982e10>:0xc104ef4>
```

My `views/twitter_aggregation_methods/_form.html.erb` is as follows:

```
<%= form_for([@twitter_source, @twitter_aggregation_method]) do |f| %>
  <% if @twitter_aggregation_method.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@twitter_aggregation_method.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this twitter_aggregation_method from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @twitter_aggregation_method.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :twitter_source_id %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :twitter_source_id, value: @twitter_source.id %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :aggregation_method %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :aggregation_method %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
```

The error points to the first line of this partial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the resources defined, `twitter_source_twitter_aggregation_methods_path` doesn't exist. Hence, the error.
You can do `rake routes` and check the `prefixes` to know what all routes exist.

From `TwitterAggregationMethods#new` you would be expecting to go to `TwitterAggregationMethods#create`, for that pass an instance of `source` in the form,

Replace

```
<%= form_for([@twitter_source, @twitter_aggregation_method]) do |f| %>
```

with

```
<%= form_for([@source, @twitter_source, @twitter_aggregation_method]) do |f| %>
```

and set `@source` in the `TwitterAggregationMethods#new`.

Comment: I've changed the form partial and create action of my twitter_aggregation_methods as suggested and it worked. I've corrected the some routing issues in my twitter_aggregation_method views using prefixes from rake routes